# What books did Symbolics Press publish?

Tags: books, lisp, symbolics

*Object-Oriented Programming in COMMON LISP: A Programmer's Guide to CLOS* by Sonya E. Keene is a well known CLOS book published in 1989 by Symbolics Press (ISBN-10: 0201175894; ISBN-13: 978-0201175899), the publishing branch of Lisp machine manufacturer Symbolics, Inc.

What other books did Symbolics Press publish? I haven't found any other than Keene's.

Comment: One of the few references I can find lists it as "Symbolics Press and Addison-Wesley". It could be that Addison-Wesley was brought in to publish it by Symbolics, and then that was never required again or the collaboration went in a different direction.

Comment: That's an interesting possibility, thanks.

Comment: 978-0-201-* would mean it's an Addison Wesley publication, wouldn't it? Thus, as Jon already mentioned, Symbolics Press might not have been a publisher in its own right. Addison-Wesley belongs to Pearson. It also seems as if the first edition was already [marked accordingly](https://www.amazon.co.jp/-/en/Sonya-Keene/dp/0201175894). So is there any indication that "Symbolics Press" existed as a company? That is other than some department/label at Symbolics. If so, address and company data may give further lead.

Comment: Book was in fact published by A-W "in association with Symbolics Press" (back cover) and "Reproduced by Addison-Wesley from camera-ready copy supplied and approved by Symbolics, Inc." and "Copyright © 1989 Symbolics, Inc." (copyright page).

Comment: I think it was fairly common back then for computer companies to have "Presses".  There are a lot of "Digital Press" books, and others.  Difference of course is that Digital published a _lot_ of manuals and stuff and so probably _was_ their own "press" (outsourcing the actual printing) so were able to have some actual _books_ on their list as well, while companies with less to publish (like Symbolics) probably were just a "press" in name and had some actual publishing company do all the work for them by arrangement.

Comment: @davidbak The basic difference is if an ISBN band is issued or not. DEC did register, got 978-0-932376-* as ISBN, thus qualifies as distinct publisher. Printing is almost always a service to be provided by third party.